# No results with python twitter search

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using python twitter to do a simple search but I'm not getting any results, even though I get results when performing the results manually. For example, I wrote a simple test script like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import twitter
api=twitter.Api()
tweets=api.GetSearch(u'東京大学',per_page=10,page=1)

for t in tweets:
    print t.text
```

If I search for 東京 (English: Tokyo), then it works, but if I increase this by 2 more characters like 東京大学 (English: Tokyo University) then nothing comes back.

Can someone tell me why? I have no ideas (T_T)

Thanks!

Comment: Also, use `u'東京大学'` instead of setting the default encoding..

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I didn't know a better way to set the encoding, but your kind comment helped and now I get one result. But only 1 result when I should get more... any ideas?

Comment: If you want to understand encodings, read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html). I'm sorry, I am not familiar enough with the Twitter search APIs to be able to give you an answer to your problem.

Comment: Ok, in any case, I appreciate your help with the encoding. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you can edit your question to remove the `.setdefaultencoding` and `reload(sys)` calls (the latter is not ever going to be needed by code like this), to focus on your problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that by adding lang="ja" within the GetSearch command, I can return more results. I suppose that the default is US English users tweeting in Japanese, which gives far fewer results than Japanese users tweeting in Japanese.